# How do I get the stats for each dimensions(device_platform, country) and it's metrics in hourly for campaign,adsets,ads with FB Graph Marketing API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to return campaigns, ad sets, ads insights in the Facebook Marketing API with breakdown country/device_platform. But I want results in HOURLY wise.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/<campaign_id>/insights/?breakdowns=device_platform,hourly_stats_aggregated_by_advertiser_time_zone&access_token=<access_token>&fields=impressions,spend,inline_clicks
```

Could someone help me to find a way to fetch the data in HOURLY?